# Access Database : Find a value in a form

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

**Situation :** I have an Access Datasheet Form which contains lots of fields (30) and about 200 records. Some of those fields are combo boxes which can contains multiple values.

**Question :** Is there a way to look for a specific value in the whole form ? 
I tried to use the Finder ( CTRL + F) but it doesn't locate the values in records containing multiple values.
The only way I know to do this so far is via the Filter for a specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (because f your reference to Ctrl-F) that you are looking for a solution to a manual 'find' - change the search options to:

[image: screen shot of search options - set Match = Any part of field]

I've just tested this on a database I'm using currently and it finds part words in multi-value combo boxes ok.

Comment: Works perfectly. I kept "Whole field" in the match section that's why. Thanks !